# R: Replace "off-diagonal" elements of a random matrix

Tags: r, matrix, replace

I'm using the following code to generate a random matrix with some elements = 1 near the diagonal, the rest = 0. (This is basically a random walk along the main diagonal.)

```
n <- 20
rw <- matrix(0, ncol = 2, nrow = n)
indx <- cbind(seq(n), sample(c(1, 2), n, TRUE))
rw[indx] <- 1
rw[,1] <- cumsum(rw[, 1])+1
rw[,2] <- cumsum(rw[, 2])+1
rw2 <- subset(rw, (rw[,1] <= 10 & rw[,2] <= 10))
field <- matrix(0, ncol = 10, nrow = 10)
field[rw2] <- 1
field

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [2,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [3,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [4,]    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    0    0     0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0     0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1     1
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

Next thing, I would like to replace the 0 elements to the right-hand/upper side of the 1-elements by 1. For the above matrix the desired output would be:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
 [2,]    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
 [3,]    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
 [4,]    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1     1
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1     1
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1     1
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1     1
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

I have tried

```
fill <- function(row) {first = match(1, row); if (is.na(first)) {row = rep(1, 10)} else {row[first:10] = 1}; return(row)}  
field2 <- apply(field, 1, fill)
field2
```

But that gives me instead:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     1
 [2,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     1
 [3,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     1
 [4,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    1     1
 [5,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    1     1
 [6,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    1     1
 [7,]    1    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    1     1
 [8,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
 [9,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
[10,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
```

Can anyone help me fix this?

Cheers,

mce

PS: If the first row is all zeros (as it can happen with the above code) it should be changed to all ones.

Comment: Do `upper.tri` and `lower.tri` come handy?

Comment: Why don't you transpose field2?

Comment: @Roman Luštrik: Not really, because the ones are not truely diagonal elements, just somewhere near the main diagonal.

Comment: @jimifiki: That's still not what I need.

Comment: @mce Why? You need a method to distunguish between a orw of zeros at the beginning and one at the bottom, isn't it?

Comment: @Richar mce just defined it. I fixed the issue about the last rows, mce, let me know if it is ok for you now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
MaxFull <- which.max((apply(field,1,sum) > 0) * (1:10))
rbind(t(apply(field[1:MaxFull,], 1, fill)),matrix(0,ncol=10,nrow=10-MaxFull))
```

notice that it uses fill as you defined it.

Comment: You're right! You need to distiguish between rows of zeros at the top or bottom of the matrix! Your code does the job! Thanks a lot, mce

Answer (score 2):

Why not just:

```
t(apply(field,1,cummax))
```

One instance:

```
dput(field)
structure(c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(10L, 
10L))

> field
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [2,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    0    0    0     0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0     0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0     0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1     1
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

The output:

```
> t(apply(field,1,cummax))
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [2,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1     1
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1     1
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1     1
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

Comment: +1 nice use of cummax. Anyway the first row of the output is wrong.

Comment: @BondedDust Result[i,j] = 0 only if (there not exists i' >= i such that field[i',j] = 1 AND there not exists j' <= j such that field[i,j'] = 1).

Comment: Can you be bit more concrete about what is wrong with the output?  What would be the correct output in this case or how to construct a counter-example?

Comment: @BondedDust As far as I understood, the first row of your example should be filled with 1s. Because the lattice elements associated with the first row lie on the upper-left side of the path.

Comment: So all the elements above and to the right of the first 1 should also be 1? Or is the rule that all the elements with a row number greater than that of the first 1 are 1's?

Answer (score 0):

In the help for the value of apply, "If each call to FUN returns a vector of length n, then apply returns an array of dimension c(n, dim(X)[MARGIN])".  So, you want the transpose of this.  Print statements were added to the fill function to confirm the operation.  You may want to check if your function is hiding another function, there is a function named fill, but it doesn't matter in this case.

```
n <- 20
rw <- matrix(0, ncol = 2, nrow = n)
indx <- cbind(seq(n), sample(c(1, 2), n, TRUE))
rw[indx] <- 1
rw[,1] <- cumsum(rw[, 1])+1
rw[,2] <- cumsum(rw[, 2])+1
rw2 <- subset(rw, (rw[,1] <= 10 & rw[,2] <= 10))
field <- matrix(0, ncol = 10, nrow = 10)
field[rw2] <- 1
field
myfill <- function(row) {
  print("Function start")
  print(row)
  first = match(1, row)
  print(paste("Match", first))
  if (is.na(first)) {
    row = rep(1, 10)
  } else {
    row[first:10] = 1
  };
  print(row)
  flush.console()
  return(row)
}  
field2 = t(apply(field, 1, myfill))
field2
```